# How to make view accessible from another schema in oracle

Tags: sql, view, oracle11g, schema, command-line-interface

I am creating table and view from admin user and granting permission to other_user for select view, using below command.

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION admin
   CREATE TABLE new_product 
      (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY, quantity NUMBER) 
   CREATE VIEW new_product_view 
      AS SELECT color, quantity FROM new_product WHERE color = 'RED' 
   GRANT select ON new_product_view TO other_user;
```

When I login from other_user, I am not able to find new_product_view from that user with error

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

How do I make view accessible from other_user?

Comment: Show us that last select as well, the one that fails.

Comment: Are you prefixing the view name with the actual owner's schema name?

Comment: @AlexPoole My bad, I was not prefixing owner's schema name while selecting. Working now.